# What's Ramaze's equivalent to Sinatra's Sinatra::NotFound?

Tags: ruby, ramaze

In other words, how do I throw a "404 - not found" in Ramaze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Innate::Helper::Redirect#respond` ([source](https://github.com/Ramaze/innate/blob/master/lib/innate/helper/redirect.rb)) method which gets included into your controller to return any response:

```
def my_action    
  respond("Response body", 404)
end
```